# Borda na intercessão entre 2 elementos - CSS

Tags: css3

Estou criando o seguinte menu:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém não estou conseguindo criar essa borda:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso criar ela com CSS?

```css
.m{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
.a{
  background: #777;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0
}
.b{
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  background: #777;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 .5rem .5rem .5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='m d-flex flex-row'>
  <div class='a'>
    <span>a</span>
    <div class='b'>
      <div class='d-flex flex-column'>
        <div><span>a1</span></div>
        <div><span>a2</span></div>
        <div><span>a3</span></div>
        <div><span>a4</span></div>
        <div><span>a5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja o código no [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/170978)

Comment: Se puderes partilhar o código já feito num jsbin, codepen ou similar, para que seja possível alguém brincar com ele, é mais fácil para ajudar. Podes só partilhar um exemplo, sem ter o código real. Porque estar a criar algo de raiz para testar uma solução é trabalhoso.

Comment: Adicionei o link na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas com CSS, podes usar os pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after`, no entanto esta solucao funciona apenas se o fundo da página for sólido.

No teu caso, como é um gradient, é possivel apenas com o `::after` usando o `border-radius` e o `box-shadow` do mesmo.

A teoria é colocar o `::after` fora do elemento *pai* e aplicar um `border-radius` conforme necessário para obter o efeito de curva desejado e usar o `box-shadow` para *preencher* o lado de fora do border com a mesma cor da tab.

Tens aqui o código:

```css
.m{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
.a{
  background: #777;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0
}
.a::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: -.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  
  border: .1rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-width: 0 0 .2rem .2rem;
  box-shadow: -.1rem 2px 0 #777;
}

/* ou usando o :before e :after - so funciona com fundos solidos */
/*.a::before {
  content: "";
  background: #777;
  position: absolute;
  right: -.5rem;
  bottom: 0rem;
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
}
.a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: 0rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
*/

.b{
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  background: #777;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 .5rem .5rem .5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='m d-flex flex-row'>
  <div class='a'>
    <span>a</span>
    <div class='b'>
      <div class='d-flex flex-column'>
        <div><span>a1</span></div>
        <div><span>a2</span></div>
        <div><span>a3</span></div>
        <div><span>a4</span></div>
        <div><span>a5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja o código funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/171356/)

Comment: Bem legal Leite, mas ta vendo que parece que ficou faltando um preenchimento na curvatura, parece que fica aparecendo um pedacinho do fundo... Para arrumar isso sugiro vc colocar os valores da sombra assim. `box-shadow: -0.1rem 2px 0 2px #777` Agora a sombra cobre todo o espaço que precisa entre os elementos. Fiz uma resposta similar, mas usando radial-gradiente para ficar mais fácil de controlar isso

Comment: Obrigado! É verdade, tem ali um pouco do fundo do site, invisível aqui no monitor do trabalho, mas em casa é um 2px por 2px, bem visível. Com a alteração sugerida, a mim aparece uma ligeira linha na direita deste elemento. Aqui no trabalho, mudar para `box-shadow: -0.1rem 3px 0 1px #777;` parece ficar correcto, e talvez seja suficiente para esconder o espaço, no entanto teria de testar em casa que é onde vejo o problema. A minha sugestão seria mesmo brincar um pouco com os valores, vai depender também um dos outros atributos visto que se está a usar REMs.

Comment: É pode ser que aparece mesmo essa linha, tem que ir ajustando os valores do box-shadow pra tentar minimizar esse "buraco" ao máximo, mas a ideia é bem legal sem dúvidas. Esses ajustes finos as vezes depende da resolução mesmo do monitor, talvez em um monitor retina seja menos perceptível, ou pior rss, infelizmente não tenho um monitor desses ou 4k para testar a renderização desses efeitos com CSS

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de resolver isso é utilizando svg. Segue um exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="left">
      This is the content on the left side
      <div class="fancy-join">
    <div class="stroke"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      This is the content on the right side
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## circle-bottom-right.svg

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="10" version="1.1" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M5,9A4,4 0 0,0 9,5L10,5L10,10L5,10Z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" d="M5,9A4,4 0 0,0 9,5"/>
</svg>
```

## circle-top-right.svg

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="10" version="1.1" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M9,5A4,4 0 0,0 5,1L5,0L10,0L10,5Z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" d="M9,5A4,4 0 0,0 5,1"/>
</svg>
```

## style.css

```
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#left, #right {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
}
#left {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0em;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
#right {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 200px;
}


.fancy-join{
  position:relative;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  left:100%;
  top:-1.5em;
  z-index:2;
}
.fancy-join .stroke{
  position:absolute;
  top: -2px;
  width:1px;
  height:2.1em;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.fancy-join .stroke:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-9px;
  top:-10px;
  background-image:url("circle-bottom-right.svg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  z-index:4;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
.fancy-join .stroke:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-9px;
  bottom: -8px;
  background-image:url("circle-top-right.svg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  z-index:4;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

Comment: Também acredito que a melhor forma de se resolver problemas com "formas" seja utilizando `<svg>`. Não é o caso dessa pergunta, mas muitas das soluções que propõem o uso somente de CSS soam como gambiarra.

Answer (score 1):

## Solução CSS

A solução desse problema pode ser feita apenas com **CSS**, utilizando dois pseudo-elementos **::after** e **::before** na class **.a**

Análise código a seguir :)

```
.a::after,
.a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;  
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.a::after {
  background: red;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.a::before {
  background: #000;  
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
.m{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
.a{
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0
}
.b{
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  background: #000;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 .5rem .5rem .5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

<div class='m d-flex flex-row'>
  <div class='a'>
    <span>a</span>
    <div class='b'>
      <div class='d-flex flex-column'>
        <div><span>a1</span></div>
        <div><span>a2</span></div>
        <div><span>a3</span></div>
        <div><span>a4</span></div>
        <div><span>a5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslimax/aq9Laaew/171297/

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma simples de fazer é com um `radial-gradient` indo to transparente para a cor que vc precisa.

Vc pode criar um pseudo elemento `::after` e nele colocar seu  `radial-gradient`. Da forma que eu fiz **não importa o tamanho do texto da Tab**, sempre vai ficar tudo alinhado `(ou vc pode colocar um valor fixo se quiser)`, vc só precisa definir os valores do `.container` se quiser...
 Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.tab {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.tab::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, transparent 0px, transparent 19.5px, #fff 20.5px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.txt {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">tab</div>
  <div class="txt">texto</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">tgdfg dfgdfab</div>
  <div class="txt">texto</div>
</div>
```